# Problem using image files in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, image, crash, onclick

I am writing an Android app, which is basically a quiz. A it contains pictures of animals and the user must click on the correct picture.
The pictures are all png files used as background pictures for button views.

The problem I have/had is with the onCLick method.
THis is the code.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view == r1){
        if (correct == 0){
            tally++;}
        total++;
        score.setText("Score: " + tally + " out of " + total );
        rg.clearFocus();
        rg.clearCheck();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quest.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        correct = nextQ();
                    }
                });

            }

        }).start();


    }

    if (view == r2){
        if (correct == 1){
            tally++;}
        total++;
        score.setText("Score: " + tally + " out of " + total );
        rg.clearFocus();
        rg.clearCheck();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quest.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        correct = nextQ();
                    }
                });

            }

        }).start();

    }

    if (view == r3){
        if (correct == 2){
            tally++;}
        total++;
        score.setText("Score: " + tally + " out of " + total );
        rg.clearFocus();
        rg.clearCheck();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quest.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        correct = nextQ();
                    }
                });

            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

r1,r2.r3 are all buttons, and quest is the question TextView. My first attempt at doing this worked fine, except one problem - it crashed a lot. I didn't use the thread you se in the code above. I also had a fourth button r4. After investigating on the internet I found that making Android search and select pictures can cause problems and it is best to put this in another thread. So I did that, and it is shown in the code above. It still crashed, so I took out the fourth button. It now works fine, but I'm not sure why.

My question is, can anyone tell me how to do this correctly? I mean when a button is clicked, new pictures are randomly generated from a section. All the pictures are stored in the drawable folder, it doesn't grab them online.

Comment: I think this might be because you're trying to modify some UI stuff from a non-UI thread. But it's hard to tell from this code segment you posted here. You should post the Exceptions thrown when these crashes happen, and the code parts where you modify the buttons. Also, consider using the AsyncTask class instead of pure java threads for background work.

Comment: Well, the problem is, the Catlog doesn't register exceptions. The screen freezes and I get the activity not responding dialog, but the catlog has a couple of vague warnings.